# Show that $\int_0^1\frac{\sqrt{\sin x}}{x}dx$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, improper-integrals

> Show that $\displaystyle\int_0^1\frac{\sqrt{\sin x}}{x}dx$ converges

I couldn't find an anti-derivative and all convergence tests I tried don't seem to work here. 
Hints are welcome.

Comment: What can you say about $$
\frac{{\sqrt {\sin x} }}{x} - \frac{1}{{\sqrt x }}
$$ for small positive $x$?

Comment: The function is defined and continuous on $(0,1].$ Use that the behavior of $\frac{\sqrt{\sin x}}{x}$ is like $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ near zero.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice that $ x\mapsto \frac{\sqrt{\sin{x}}}{x} $ is continuous and positive on $ \left(0,1\right] $ so we can use the comparaison test : $$ \left(\forall x\in\left[0,1\right]\right),\ \sin{x}\leq x $$

Thus : $$ \left(\forall x\in\left(0,1\right]\right),\ \frac{\sqrt{\sin{x}}}{x}\leq\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} $$

Since $ \int_{0}^{1}{\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{x}}} $ converges, $ \int_{0}^{1}{\frac{\sqrt{\sin{x}}}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x} $ converges.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Taylor expansion of $\sin(x)$ and then the binomial expansion to get
$$\sqrt{\sin(x)}=x^{1/2}-\frac{x^{5/2}}{12}+\frac{x^{9/2}}{1440}+O\left(x^{11/2}\right)$$
$$\frac{\sqrt{\sin (x)}}{x}=x^{-1/2}-\frac{x^{3/2}}{12}+\frac{x^{7/2}}{1440}+O\left(x^{9/2}\right)$$
$$\int \frac{\sqrt{\sin (x)}}{x}\, dx=2 x^{1/2}-\frac{x^{5/2}}{30}+\frac{x^{9/2}}{6480}+O\left(x^{11/2}\right)$$
$$\int_0^1 \frac{\sqrt{\sin (x)}}{x}\, dx \sim \frac{2549}{1296} \approx 1.966821$$ while numerical integration would give                                        $1.966814$